# Link + Div + Hover + Background

Tags: css, html, hover

I want to display menu points on my new homepage.

A menu point contains several elements -> Icon + Title + Description.
Those menu points should be links, so I just wrote  `a href` in front of it.
It works, but it looks creepy, because it changes the background colour to grey. (Even if I declare it to white).

**CSS**

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'WebSymbolsRegular';
src: url('websymbols/websymbols-regular-webfont.eot');
src: url('websymbols/websymbols-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('websymbols/websymbols-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
    url('websymbols/websymbols-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('websymbols/websymbols-regular-webfont.svg#WebSymbolsRegular') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}

A { text-decoration: none; }
A:link {text-decoration: none}
A:visited {text-decoration: none}
A:active {text-decoration: none}
A:hover { text-decoration: none; }
A:focus { outline: none; }

.menuePoint {
width: 300px;
height: 70px;
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
float: none;
overflow: hidden;
text-align: left;
background: #fff;
padding-left: 10px;
}

.menuePointIcon {
font-family: 'WebSymbolsRegular', cursive;
font-size: 20px;
float:left;
display:block;
text-shadow: 0px 0px 25px #0f76a6;
color: #0f76a6;
line-height: 66px;
width: 90px;
left: 0px;
text-align: center;
-webkit-transition: all 400ms linear;
-moz-transition: all 400ms linear;
-o-transition: all 400ms linear;
-ms-transition: all 400ms linear;
transition: all 400ms linear;
}

.menuePointTitle {
font-size: 25px;
-webkit-transition: all 300ms linear;
-moz-transition: all 300ms linear;
-o-transition: all 300ms linear;
-ms-transition: all 300ms linear;
}

.menuePointDesc {
font-size: 18px;
color: #666;
-webkit-transition: all 300ms linear;
-moz-transition: all 300ms linear;
-o-transition: all 300ms linear;
-ms-transition: all 300ms linear;
transition: all 300ms linear;
}

.menuePoint:hover .menuePointTitle {
opacity: 1;
color:#2676ac;
-webkit-animation:menuePointTitleAnimation 2s;
}

.menuePoint:hover .menuePointDesc {
-webkit-animation:menuePointDescAnimation 2s;
}

.menuePoint:hover .menuePointIcon {
font-size: 35px;
color: #0f76a6;
text-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #0f76a6;
opacity: 1;
}

@-webkit-keyframes menuePointTitleAnimation /* Safari and Chrome */
{
  from {
     -webkit-transform: translateX(110%);
  }

  50% {
     -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
  }

  to {
     -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes menuePointDescAnimation /* Safari and Chrome */
{
  from {
     -webkit-transform: translateX(-110%);
  }

  50% {
     -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
  }

  to {
     -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
    <div style="text-align: center;">
        <div class="menuePoint">
            <div class="menuePointIcon">A</div>
            <div class="menuePointTitle">Test</div>
            <div class="menuePointDesc">Test</div>
        </div>

        <div class="menuePoint">
            <div class="menuePointIcon">B</div>
            <div class="menuePointTitle">WiFi</div>
            <div class="menuePointDesc">Educ</div>
        </div>

        <a href="#">
        <div class="menuePoint">
            <div class="menuePointIcon">C</div>
            <div class="menuePointTitle">Kontakt</div>
            <div class="menuePointDesc">Email / Jobs</div>
        </div>
        </a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying a `border-width: 0px`.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of this specific behaviour when the background becomes grey?

Comment: Of course :) Its like on the screenshot which i mentioned in the post.
http://www.fotos-hochladen.net/view/problemk1zm7540qh.png

Comment: Here an other screenshot
http://img5.fotos-hochladen.net/uploads/problem23km5l7qcrp.png

Comment: Do you have a link so I can access the file and see the source?

Comment: Well, as I could see from the last screenshot, this behaviour is related to when the link is hovered.
Can you check on Google Chrome what happens when you hover the link?
Like changes on border, margin, padding or something?

Comment: i posted the whole code. But if it helps you here are the files: ct-projekte.square7.ch/Files.rar

Comment: Well, how can i record the differences? I just used the "F12" tool to determine the differences. But how can i "record" them? Sorry, usualy I dont design websites :)

Comment: Thats the profile if i record it

con
100.0%
109
.menuePointDesc
0.0%
57
div
0.0%
369
.menuePoint:hover .menuePointDesc
0.0%
56
a
0.0%
2
a:link
0.0%
2
.menuePoint:hover .menuePointTitle
0.0%
160
a:-webkit-any-link:active
0.0%
0
a:-webkit-any-link
0.0%
2
.menuePoint
0.0%
2
a:hover
0.0%
1
a:visited
0.0%
2
a:active
0.0%
0
.menuePoint:hover .menuePointIcon
0.0%
56
.menuePointTitle
0.0%
201
a:link, a:visited, a:active, a:hover
0.0%
5
a:hover
0.0%
1
a

Comment: Well, I can't determine what is the problem here... As soon as you get this site online let me know, paste the link here and I'll take a look!

Comment: Hello! The Homepage is online. Please have a look: www.scf-software.com

Comment: It seems like a browser behaviour since it varies from browser to browser. Have you tested it on Firefox to see how the site looks like?

Comment: It tested it on several browsers, always with borders!!! But i dont want that borders xD